# ruby version manager (while installing rvm had an following memory error)

Tags: ruby, rvm

while installing RVM had an following error

No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/ruby-2.1.3.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Not enough space (29MB) to install ruby (440MB).

Comment: Make some more space on your drive?

Comment: I already had a 32 GB free space in my disk.

Answer (score 0):

compare `echo $rvm_path` with `df -h` - the longest path prefix is the one that has to have place for installing ruby.

you can reconfigure many rvm sub paths with `rvm user` and editing `~/.rvmrc` - but you have to ensure the new paths exist and are writable by rvm